# Java Outputs Wrong Unicode Value of Subscript 9 - VS Code IDE

Tags: java, terminal, fonts, char, ascii

In my code, I am trying to get an input from the user (subscript 9) and print the Unicode value of said value. I get the input, make it a char, find the Unicode of it, but get 0 as the Unicode value (with 8329 being what it should be for reference)

```
class java{

   public static void main(String args[]){
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       String lower = sc.next();
       char[] arr  = lower.toCharArray();
       System.out.println((int)arr[0] + "  "  + (int)'₉');
       sc.close();

   }
}
```

Terminal:

0  8329

As you see, when I run the code, I ask it to print (int)arr[0] (Which is the subscript 9 inputted into the terminal, indicated by the red dot) - however it says the Unicode is 0. I try the same code in repl.it, and it works. But not in visual studio code. I want it to work in visual studio code, and I am trying to figure out what the issue is.

Some things I have tried is looking at my font: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApRxk.jpg
. This should be good? I thought that Menlo, Monaco, 'FreeSans', and monospace should support being able to grab a subscript 9. I also ran it in python in visual studios, and it works perfectly fine.
Windows Locale is set to support UTF-8.
Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Please don't post images of text.

Comment: @tgdavies thank you for your advice. I have made it into code and manually said what the input is. Thanks! :0

Comment: Your code prints `8329  8329` for me. I suspect your terminal is not doing Unicode input correctly. (I guess you know that `₉` is not an ASCII character)

Comment: oh whoops. It is a UTF-8 character then?
How do I make sure my terminal does unicode input correctly? Any advice @tgdavies

Comment: It's a Unicode character, U+2089. The encoding of that character in UTF-8 would be three bytes: `0xE2 0x82 0x89`. The encoding in UTF-16 (which is what Java Strings use) is `0x2089` (which is decimal 8329 of course)

Comment: So would that mean I would have to use UTF-16, not UTF-8? Sorry, I am a pretty beginner coder. Also how would I go about fixing this @tgdavies

Comment: I don't use VSCode for Java, sorry.

Comment: Although "not forcing the user to type unicode characters" seems like a good route to take!

Comment: Unfortunately it cannot be avoided, as it takes in chemistry text (which require subscripts)

Comment: This is Python, but might give you some ideas https://jwilk.github.io/chemiscripts/

Comment: Thanks, but I won't be able to use that, sorry :( - I need to do everything with my code only
Interestingly enough, it works just fine when I take the text from input.txt, but when I take it from the terminal is when it becomes wierd.